# Maximum Modulus Principle Corollary

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi.
I can't find an example of when inequality holds from the following corollary of the maximum modulus principle.

> Suppose that $\Omega$ is a region with compact closure $\bar \Omega$. If $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\bar \Omega$, then $$ \sup_{z \in \Omega} | f(z)| \leq \sup_{z \in \bar\Omega - \Omega} |f(z)|.$$ In fact, since $f(z)$ is continuous on the compact set $\bar\Omega$, $|f(z)|$ attains its maximum in $\bar\Omega$; but this cannot be in $\Omega$ is $f$ is non-constant. If $f$ is constant, the conclusion is trivial.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such example. Suppose otherwise, let $s_1=\sup_{z\in\Omega}|f(z)|$ and let $s_2=\sup_{z\in\overline\Omega\setminus\Omega}|f(z)|$. You are assuming that $s_1<s_2$. Since $\overline\Omega$ is compact and $\Omega$ is an open set, $\overline\Omega\setminus\Omega$ is compact too. So, there is some $w\in\overline\Omega\setminus\Omega$ such that $|f(w)|=s_2$. But $w=\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n$ for some sequence $w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots$ of elements of $\Omega$, and therefore $|f(w)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(w_n)|$. But this is impossible, since $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|f(w_n)|\le s_1$.